# AndroidManifest.xml error after upgrading to the latest version in my flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

**This was after going through the steps [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects)**

I keep getting this error after following the steps above **"Error parsing LocalFile: '/home/user/Projects/xylophone-flutter/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml' Please ensure that the android manifest is a valid XML document and try again."**

I'm using the latest [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) dart package, which requires the upgrade. After following the steps in the documentation I have stumbled across this error. I've gone through and checked my syntax, and my IDE doesn't show any problem areas. I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any help or feedback is greatly appreciated.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml code: `

```
<!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
     flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
     to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
     calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
     In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
     additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
     FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
<application>
</application>
    <activity
        android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
             until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
             there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
             defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application
    >
```

`

Comment: You have closed `application` tag twice.

Comment: @AlphaOne Wow, I feel silly. I must have skimmed over this code 5 different times trying to find the error. Is my junior-ness showing yet? Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
     calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
     In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
     additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
     FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
<application
    android:label="xylophone"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported = "true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
             until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
             there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
             defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).